# How to go from $x_{p}\frac{dx_{p}}{dt}$ to $\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{1}{2}x_{p}^{2})$?

Tags: derivatives

I have the following example:

[Example that contains my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aSEM.png)

I cannot seem to find out how they go from $ x_{p}\frac{dx_{p}}{dt}$ to $\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{1}{2}x_{p}^{2})$.

Comment: Do you know how to compute (or "expand") the derivative $\frac{d}{dt}(x_p^2/2)$ (using the chain rule)? Recall the rule: $\frac{df(x)}{dt} = \frac{df(x)}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$.

Comment: If you integrate and then take the derivative with respect to the same variable, you get your original expression back.